# How to make a sticky scrolling effect that stays at the top a little and immediately pops off

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry for such a dumb question for you, I've got a list of elements with overflow-y:auto, like this: [image]

I'd like to make them stick for just a little bit when I'm scrolling and pop off when the next one is pushing it from the bottom.

It's to avoid this which IMO doesn't look very good. [image]

I know I have to use position:sticky but I don't know how to achieve this without the elements staying there definitely as I scroll down

Comment: That sounds like a neat effect! `sticky` isn't what you're after, as it will certainly leave the element sticking to the top of the screen

Comment: thanks, that helps me to not be stuck with sticky in vain, I think I might need to use javascript to detect a scroll event (if that's possible) and according to the position of the scroll bar switch the element between position:relative and position:fixed or something similar

Comment: Yes, you can't achieve this using pure CSS. Javascript sounds like the right path to go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please excuse the lengthy code, as the HTML and parts of the CSS were just meant to make things stand out.

The actual core of it is the JavaScript code, along with the parts of CSS I didn't comment on.

Obviously the code's readability can be improved; However I've intentionally left the original functions, rather than writing custom ones (e.g. `makeTopElement(element)`, or `getTopPosition(element)`), as the code snippet has already become pretty long vertically.

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const itemHeight = items[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
let currentTopIndex = 0;
let prevY = 0;

document.onscroll = function() {
  let currY = window.pageYOffset;

  // Scrolling down
  if (currY > prevY &&
      currentTopIndex < items.length - 1 &&
      items[currentTopIndex + 1].getBoundingClientRect().top < itemHeight) {
    items[currentTopIndex].classList.remove('top');
    items[currentTopIndex].style.top = 'auto';
    items[currentTopIndex].style.bottom = 0;
    currentTopIndex ++;
    items[currentTopIndex].classList.add('top');
  }

  // Scrolling up
  else if (currY < prevY &&
           currentTopIndex > 0 &&
           items[currentTopIndex - 1].getBoundingClientRect().top > 0) {
      items[currentTopIndex].classList.remove('top');
      currentTopIndex --;
      items[currentTopIndex].classList.add('top');
      items[currentTopIndex].style.top = 0;
      items[currentTopIndex].style.bottom = 'auto';
  }

  prevY = currY;
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
}

.itemWrapper {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  
  /* These properties are here just to make things pretty */
  background-color: MintCream;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #00e673;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  /* These properties are here just to make things pretty */
  background-color: red;
  border-color: #990000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="itemWrapper">
    <div class="item top">
      first
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrapper">
    <div class="item">
      second
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrapper">
    <div class="item">
      third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to make this you would use css-snap:

for the list class: add the following css:

```
.parent { 
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(50px);
}
.child { 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

replace:

`.parent` with your list class,

`height: 200px` with your list height, notice that you should give it specific height,

`scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(50px)` replace 50px with height of children, in my case i used 50px because child class has height of 50px.

`.child` with your element class

`height: 50px` height of children element.

```css
.parent { 
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(50px);
}
.child { 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.child:nth-child(even) { 
background-color: #ccc;
}
.child:nth-child(odd) { 
    background-color: #ddd;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
      <div class="child"><h1>testing</h1></div>
  </div>
```